# Ignoring Null Values

Tags: powershell

I have a question regarding Null values.

The script below works fine, but will return errors when nothing is in my Z (optical drive). Obviously if nothing is in the optical drive it is basically null, but I have not found a way around that as of yet.  I know it's probably a simple fix and am hoping someone here can help.

```
Function GetDisk
{
    Param(
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [Switch]$PassThru
    )
    # ... 
}

Function Get-ColorSplat
{
    # Create color Splats
    $C1 = @{ForegroundColor="Green"}
    $C2 = @{ForegroundColor="Yellow"}
    $C3 = @{ForegroundColor="Red"}


    # Create color constants in the previous scope.
    New-Variable -Name "Good" -Value $C1 -Scope 1
    New-Variable -Name "Problem" -Value $C2 -Scope 1
    New-Variable -Name "Bad" -Value $C3 -Scope 1

} # End: Get-ColorSplat

Function Write-ColorOutput
{
    Param($DiskInfo)

    Write-Host""
    Write-Host -NoNewLine "OS Version: "

    Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  Caption | ForEach{ $_.Caption }

    Write-Host""

    # Display the headers.
    Write-host "SystemName DeviceID VolumeName         Size(GB)   FreeSpace(GB) %FreeSpace(GB)  Date"
    Write-host "---------- -------- -----------        --------   ------------  --------------  ----------------"

    # Display the data.
    ForEach ($D in $DiskInfo)
    {
        $PSComputerName = $D.PSComputerName.PadRight(6)
        $DeviceID = $D.DeviceID.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)
        $VolumeName = $D.VolumeName.ToString().PadRight(20).Remove(19)
        $SizeGB = $D.SizeGB.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)
        $FSGB = $D.FreeSpaceGB.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)
        $PFS = $D.PercentFS.ToString().PadRight(7).Remove(6)
        $Date = $D.Date.ToString().PadRight(20).Remove(19)

        If ($D.PercentFS -ge 50)
        { Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)      $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" @Good }
        ElseIf (($D.PercentFS -lt 50) -and ($D.PercentFS -GE 40))
        { Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)      $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" @Problem }
        Else
        { Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)      $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" @Bad }
     }
}

# Get the color splats
Get-ColorSplat

    $DiskInfo = Get-WMIObject win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $env:computername | Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceID, Size, VolumeName,
        @{name="SizeGB"; expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1gb)}},
        @{Name="FreeSpaceGB"; expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}},
        @{Name="PercentFS"; expression={"{0:N2}%" -f(($_.FreeSpace/$_.size)*100)}},
        @{name="Date"; expression={$(Get-Date -Format "g")}} 
        #$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'

    If (!$PassThru) {
        Write-ColorOutput -DiskInfo $DiskInfo
    }
    Else {
        Write-Output $DiskInfo
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, `VolumeName` and `PercentFS` are null for your `Z:` drive. That cause exception, when you call `ToString()` on them.

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct, but I just can't figure out a way around it.  Have been researching how to deal with null values but have not got anything to work as of yet

Comment: New-Variable -Name [...] the new variable creation will cause a problem as well once you correct the $null issue... I'm working on a "working version" right now

Comment: That basically works, however it breaks the column formatting.  Values for VolumeName and PercentFreespace are moved considerably left

Comment: and btw - thank you for lending a hand

Comment: `$VolumeName = $(if($null -eq $D.VolumeName) { '>>>NULL<<<' } else { $D.VolumeName}).ToString().PadRight(20).Remove(19)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to problems several values of $D were returning $null but you aren't checking their value (e.g. $D.VolumeName).
The second problem is that you are creating the global variables multiple times (e.g. New-Variable -Name "Good").

I suggest you refactor so that variable creation is in "Get-ColorSplat" if you are going to call it several times.

Edit #1 fixed padding in output table

```
Function GetDisk
{
    Param(
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [Switch]$PassThru
    )
    # ... 
}

Function Get-ColorSplat
{
    # Create color Splats
    $C1 = @{ForegroundColor="Green"}
    $C2 = @{ForegroundColor="Yellow"}
    $C3 = @{ForegroundColor="Red"}


    # Create color constants in the previous scope.
    if(Get-Variable Good -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){}
    else{New-Variable -Name "Good" -Value $C1 -Scope 1}

    if(Get-Variable Problem -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){}
    else{New-Variable -Name "Problem" -Value $C2 -Scope 1}

    if(Get-Variable Bad -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){}
    else{New-Variable -Name "Bad" -Value $C3 -Scope 1}

} # End: Get-ColorSplat

Function Write-ColorOutput
{
    Param($DiskInfo)

    Write-Host""

    Write-Host -NoNewLine "OS Version: "

    Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  Caption | ForEach{ $_.Caption }

    Write-Host""

    # Display the headers.
    Write-host "SystemName DeviceID VolumeName         Size(GB)   FreeSpace(GB) %FreeSpace(GB)  Date"
    Write-host "---------- -------- -----------        --------   ------------  --------------  ----------------"

    # Display the data.
    ForEach ($D in $DiskInfo)
    {
    $PSComputerName = $D.PSComputerName.PadRight(6)
    $DeviceID = $D.DeviceID.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)

    $Dname = $D.VolumeName
    if($Dname){$VolumeName =     $D.VolumeName.ToString().PadRight(20).Remove(19)}
    else{$VolumeName = '                   '}

    $SizeGB = $D.SizeGB.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)
    $FSGB = $D.FreeSpaceGB.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)

    $PercentFS = $D.PercentFS
    if($PercentFS){$PFS = $D.PercentFS.ToString().PadRight(7).Remove(6)}
    else{$PFS = '      '}

    $Date = $D.Date.ToString().PadRight(20).Remove(19)

    If ($D.PercentFS -ge 50)
    { Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)      $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" @Good }
    ElseIf (($D.PercentFS -lt 50) -and ($D.PercentFS -GE 40))
    { Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)      $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" @Problem }
    Else
    { Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)      $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" @Bad }

    }
}

# Get the color splats
Get-ColorSplat

$DiskInfo = Get-WMIObject win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName     $env:computername | Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceID, Size, VolumeName,
        @{name="SizeGB"; expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1gb)}},
        @{Name="FreeSpaceGB"; expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}},
        @{Name="PercentFS"; expression={"{0:N2}%" -f(($_.FreeSpace/$_.size)*100)}},
        @{name="Date"; expression={$(Get-Date -Format "g")}} 
        #$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'

 If (!$PassThru) {Write-ColorOutput -DiskInfo $DiskInfo}
 Else {Write-Output $DiskInfo}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.  I've been working on this for two days (it's been snowing where I live in the Rockies) and you got it in a few minutes.  Thank you Thank you Thank you.  Am an old dog(60 years old) trying to learn new things. Now I just have to figure out just exactly what you did so I can learn from it

Comment: One last thing - for some reason (with your script above) I am no longer able to retrieve Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption.  The OS Version shows up but it is blank

Comment: @RoadGlide Not sure it works for me I even copied the above to make sure there wasn't a formatting issue in the powershell.  I get 'OS Version: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro' in my output.  Are you expecting more OS information then that?

Comment: No worries – I figured it out.  Wanted to thank you again.  I had most of the script the way I wanted, but for some reason was having difficulty with null values.  Your help also got me thinking about the “Function  -Get Color Splat” that I had in the script, it didn’t need to be there so I got rid of it.  Am new here (60 years old and for some crazy reason I decided to learn powershell last week) your help is very much appreciated.  Will post my script in "Answer Your Question" can't figure out how to do it In "Add Comment"

Comment: @RoadGlide Please also accept my answer so I get the points for the assistance. I must say for 60 you're making tremendous strides. You're about my father's age and I can't imagine him taking on PowerShell coding.

Comment: I will of course accept your answer. You saved me a lot of grief when I was getting very frustrated.  My dad would always say try to learn new things from time to time if you don't you get old very quickly.

Comment: One last thing - how do I "accept" your answer?  I know that's a lame question but I brew my own beer and have got about a pint and a half in me right now

Comment: @RoadGlide don't feel bad about asking i had to look up how to accept an answer myself. I'm a new user to the site as well. There should be a gray check mark next to my answer click it and it should turn green. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Got it...Thanks again...you have been the most helpful person I've communicated with so far and I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out - thanks to all that commented and helped me.

Function GetDisk
{
    Param(
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [Switch]$PassThru
    )

```
Function Write-ColorOutput
{  
    Param($DiskInfo)

    Write-Host""

    Write-Host -NoNewLine "OS Version: "

    Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  Caption | ForEach{ $_.Caption }

    Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object CSName, InstallDate, BuildNumber, OSArchitecture, BootDevice | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green

    Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object $env:computername, FriendlyName, SerialNumber, MediaType, OperationalStatus, HealthStatus | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green

    Write-Host""

    # Display the headers.
    Write-host "SystemName DeviceID VolumeName         Size(GB)  FreeSpace(GB) %FreeSpace(GB)  Date"
    Write-host "---------- -------- -----------        --------  ------------  --------------  ----------------"

    # Display the data.
    ForEach ($D in $DiskInfo)
    {
        $PSComputerName = $D.PSComputerName.PadRight(6)
        $DeviceID = $D.DeviceID.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)
        $Dname = $D.VolumeName
        if($Dname){$VolumeName = $D.VolumeName.ToString().PadRight(20).Remove(19)} else{$VolumeName = '                   '}
        $SizeGB = $D.SizeGB.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)
        $FSGB = $D.FreeSpaceGB.ToString().PadRight(6).Remove(5)
        $PercentFS = $D.PercentFS
        if($PercentFS){$PFS = $D.PercentFS.ToString().PadRight(7).Remove(6)} else{$PFS = '      '}
        $Date = $D.Date.ToString().PadRight(20).Remove(19)

        If ($D.PercentFS -ge 50)
         {Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)     $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" -ForegroundColor Green}
        ElseIf (($D.PercentFS -lt 50) -and ($D.PercentFS -GE 40))
         {Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)     $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" -ForegroundColor Yellow}
        Else 
         {Write-Host "$PSComputerName    $($DeviceID)    $($VolumeName)$($SizeGB)     $($FSGB)         $($PFS)          $($Date)" -ForegroundColor Red} 

    }

    Get-PhysicalDisk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select-Object $env:computername, PowerOnHours, Temperature, Wear, ReadErrorsTotal, WriteErrorsTotal, FlushLatencyMax, WriteLatencyMax | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green

    Disk | Select-Object | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green
}

    $DiskInfo = Get-WMIObject win32_logicalDisk -ComputerName $env:computername | Select-Object PSComputerName, DeviceID, Size, VolumeName,

        @{name="SizeGB"; expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size/1gb)}},
        @{Name="FreeSpaceGB"; expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}},
        @{Name="PercentFS"; expression={"{0:N2}%" -f(($_.FreeSpace/$_.size)*100)}},
        @{name="Date"; expression={$(Get-Date -Format "g")}} 
        #$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'



 If (!$PassThru) {Write-ColorOutput -DiskInfo $DiskInfo} Else {Write-Output $DiskInfo}

 Write-Host""
 Write-Host""
```

}